# How to detect cracks on tiles?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to detect cracks on tiles. I used canny, but it didn't work well.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to give a little more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult one to do by just using edge detection, especially because of the patterns on the tiles. I suggest collecting a large number of photos of tiles and using a deep learning approach. You can find a few examples of deep lerning at pyimagesearch.com.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be a process of elimination:

- Figure out where the **outer** edges of the tile are.
- Any edges which are not the outer edges might be cracks.
- Look at the original image and find something different about the cracks vs the textures. Some ideas:

  - High local frequency
  - Color
  - Shape
  - Singular/converging point
  - Jaggedness
  - Intensity
  - Size
- Use some method to determine if any remaining edges are cracks:

  - Energy methods
  - Deep learning

Comment: Do you know some codes using python opencv to solve the question ?